# Get the ID of parent DIV when content is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamically-generated

Inside a main "DIV_Container" I have a series of dynamically created DIVs which appear on the click of some button. Each div has an assigned ID such as "DIV_1, DIV2, DIV_n" etc, and they all have a class of 'div_sub_dyn'. Inside each one of these dyn created divs, there is also a image, so I have a file that looks like:

```
<div id="DIV_Container">  //or id="div_shirts_container"
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_1">        
        <img src="image_1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_2">
        <img src="image_2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_3">
        <img src="image_3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:::
I want to grab the 'DIV_n' id of the respective sub-div whenever the user clicks on the contained image, or on any other item contained inside the DIV_n ( I plan to add more tags/elements). Right now, when the user clicks on the Image, only the Image ID is returned (blank), when he clicks on the area surrounging the image (there is a margin) belonging to the DIV_n, only THEN the 'DIV_n' id is returned. How do I get the click to return the ID of the DIV_n even when anything inside the DIV_n is clicked?

Right now, among other functions I have the following two choices of jQuery functions:

```
$(document)ready(function(){    
    $("#DIV_Container").click(function(e){
    alert(e.target.id); 
    });
//or
    $("#DIV_Container").on('click','.div_sub_dyn',function(e){ 
    alert(e.target.id); 
    });
```

Many thanks, would really appreciate any help. Stay safe during this Coronavirus period.

Comment: Any reason you added `// or id=div_shirts_container` - what is that can you explain that part as well.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysHelping, I removed the comment, it was another typo, and got an answer based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following clarification that `.shirt_item` was the containing div, not the image, slight update:

---

Use your event delegation option, where `.div_sub_dyn` is the div that *contains* the image, you can use:

```
$("#div_shirts_container").on('click', '.div_sub_dyn', function(e){
    console.log(this.id);  
});
```

As clarified in the contents, when using `function(e) { }`, `this` becomes the filtered target, in this case `.div_sub_dyn`.

Using `() =>` will need `e.currentTarget` (as also detailed in the other answer)

Note that technically you might be clicking on the image itself (eg in this snippet the image takes up the whole div), *event bubbling* will mean that, if the image does not have its own `click` handler, the event will keep bubbling up to the parent item (and next parent etc) until it finds an event handler.

```js
$("#DIV_Container").on("click", ".div_sub_dyn", function() {
    var id = this.id;
    console.log("Clicked:", id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIV_Container">
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_1">        
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg" width=150>
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_2">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width=150>
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_3">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg" width=300>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Using the HTML in the question clicking on the `img` (original assumption that .shirt_item was the image):

```js
$("#DIV_Container").on("click", "img", function() {

    var id = $(this).closest(".div_sub_dyn").attr("id")

    console.log("Clicked:", id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIV_Container">
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_1">        
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg" width=150>
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_2">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width=150>
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_3">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg" width=300>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sorry, I made an error, instead of '_shirt_item' it should be '.div_sub_dyn'. I want to put it on the dynamic DIV, which contains the image. So does using `$( selector1 ).on( event, selector2, fn())` attach the event to the selector2 element? i.e. does selector2 become "this" or is it back to "selector1"? I am i correct to say its selector2 since you used 'this'?

Comment: Using the snippet above - `img` becomes `this` (selector2 in your comment) - so what you click on goes into the event.  It doesn't "attach the event to selector2" as it uses event delegation.  *Technically*: it attaches the event to selector1 (so that must exist) and then filters event handlers to those that match selector2.

Comment: Ah great, that explains it. Thanks buddy!!

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to explain man, really appreciate it!!

Comment: No worries, added a 2nd snippet now you've clarified the shirt_item.  You can filter event delegation on anything - the image or the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `target` you can use [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) which refers to the ***element that listens to the event*** where as `target` refers to the ***element that triggered the event***:

**Demo:**

```js
$("#DIV_Container").on('click', '.div_sub_dyn', function(e){
  var targetId = e.currentTarget.id;  
  console.log(targetId); 
});
```

```css
.div_sub_dyn{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIV_Container">
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_1">        
        <img src="image_1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_2">
        <img src="image_2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class='div_sub_dyn' id="DIV_3">
        <img src="image_3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worth adding?  "and takes advantage of event bubbling"

Comment: @Mamun .. thanks a lot mate, I didnt know I could use CurrentTarget, its new to me. thanks a ton for that!